# Find the index value of similar items in array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I created a for loop that will pinpoint the location when name and DB are the same value. The problem is if there is a value that is not present in name, the index becomes -2, and will be -2 for the rest of the array even when the values are present in both arrays.

How can I fix this? Also, is there a way to print out the values from the name array that are indexed -2 and to check for duplicates in DB?

For example:

```
DB = ['a','b','g','f','g']
name = ['a','e','b','p']

code output: [0, -2, -2, -2]

wanted output: [0, -2, 1, -2]
The following is a list of name not present in the DB array: e,p
The calculation has been aborted, there is a duplicate DB: g
```

Code:

```
DB = ['a','b','g','f','g']
name = ['a','e','b','p']

wanted_columns=[-2 for a in range(len(name))]

try:
    for i in range(0,len(name)):
        wanted_columns[i] = DB.index(name[i])
        
except ValueError:
    print('The following is a list of tags not present in the DB array: {}' .format(name[i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `try/except` inside the loop. Your code ends the loop when the exception happens.

When if you do it this way, you don't need to pre-fill the list, you can use `append()`.

```
DB = ['a','b','g','f','g']
name = ['a','e','b','p']
indexes = []
wanted_columns = []

for val in name:
    try:
        indexes.append(DB.index(val))
    except:
        indexes.append(-2)
        wanted_columns.append(val)

print(f'Indexes: {indexes}')
print(f'The following is a list of tags not present in the DB array: {",".join(wanted_columns)}')
```

Comment: Thank you! It works with the example, but for some reason it won't work with my actual data. The entire indexes becomes -2. My DB is outputting as a list (0 a, 1 b, 2 g) while name is outputting as an array ['a','e','b']. Do you know how I can fix this? I'm using this to upload data ||df=pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8').fillna(0)|| name=df.columns.values.tolist() ||valueDB=pd.read_csv('filename',sep='/').fillna(0) || DB = valueDB.loc[:,'filename'].str.strip()|| I think it's because of DB. I just don't know how to fix it. I tried changing it into an np.array except nothing happened

Comment: I suspect you have the wrong separator when you read the CSV. There's a space between `0` and `a`, not `/`.

Comment: It's a '|' value. Python changes it to '/' for some reason

Comment: I doubt very much that it does that, something else must be going on. Anyway, that's a completely separate problem, you should open a new question if you need help fixing it.

Comment: You can fix DB with `DB = [el.split()[-1] for el in DB]`

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is it correcting the data into an array? Why do I have to do that for it to read the values?

Comment: WIthout seeing the CSV files involved, I can't tell.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help again. I really appreciate it. I've been stuck on this problem for a while

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you hit an error in your for loop, the except statement is executed, and the script terminates (the other iterations won't be run). Move the try-except statement inside the for loop.

```
DB = ['a','b','g','f','g']
name = ['a','e','b','p']

wanted_columns=[-2 for a in range(len(name))]


for i in range(0,len(name)):
    try:
        wanted_columns[i] = DB.index(name[i]) 
    except ValueError:
        print('The following is a list of tags not present in the DB array:' .format(wanted_columns[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The answer to the first question is putting `for` loop outside the `try...except` statement.

```py
unique_name = []
for i in range(0,len(name)):
    try:
        wanted_columns[i] = DB.index(name[i])
    except ValueError:
        unique_name.append(name[i])
print('The following is a list of tags not present in the DB array: {}' .format(','.join(unique_name)))
```

BTW, I provide another solution to do this.

```py
wanted_columns = [ DB.index(v) if DB.count(v) else -2 for v in name ]
unique_name = [ v for v in name if v not in DB ]
```

2. As for `checking for duplicates in DB`, you can also use `count()`.

```py
duplicates = { v for v in DB if DB.count(v) > 1 }
print('The calculation has been aborted, there is a duplicate DB: {}'.format(','.join(duplicates)))
```